# What is the right way to convert Variant to proper type?

Tags: types, d, type-conversion, phobos

I use `mysql-native` that return [Variant](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant.html) data type. I need to convert it to standard types like `int`, `string` etc.

D have `std.conv`, but `std.variant` also have methods for concretion.

I can't understand what difference between: `get`, `coerce`, `toString` and `to` (from `std.conv`).

Also it's sound very strange that `convertsTo` is return `bool`. By it's name I expected that it should do convention. IMHO `isConvertable` is more proper name for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to get the value from a `Variant` type:

- [`Variant.peek!T`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant.html#.VariantN.peek): If the value currently being held by the `Variant` object is of type `T`, then a pointer to that value is returned. If it is holding a value of a different type, it returns null instead.

  ```
  Variant v = "42";
  string* ptr = v.peek!string;
  assert(ptr !is null && *ptr == "42");
  ```
- [`Variant.get!T`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant.html#.VariantN.get): If the value currently being held by the `Variant` object is of type `T`, return the value of it. Otherwise, a `VariantException` is thrown.

  ```
  Variant v = "42";
  assertThrown!VariantException(v.get!int);
  assertNotThrown!VariantException(v.get!string);
  ```
- [`Variant.coerce!T`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant.html#.VariantN.coerce): Returns the value currently held by the `Variant` object, explicitly convertedto type `T`. If the value cannot be converted to type `T`, then an `Exception` is thrown.

  ```
  Variant v = "42";
  string s = v.coerce!string;
  assert(s == "42");
  int i = v.coerce!int;
  assert(i == 42);
  ```

Comment: Could you add example from real life. As I understand main problem if Variable can explicitly to cast to proper data-type?